# Извлечение даты и времени из строки

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Импортирую таблицу *csv* (детализацию разговоров) в MySQL с помощью *phpMyAdmin*. Все поля таблицы в *MySQL* — текстовые. Есть поле с датой/временем в одной ячейке вида `27.06.2015 8:53:07` или `27.06.2015 11:48:57`.

Допустим, в моей таблице есть поля `s`, `d`, `t` (`t` - это дата/время). Как мне после загрузки выбрать все значения, разбить дату/время на дату и время в формате данных *MySQL* и записать в другую таблицу?

Comment: Забыл указать что пишу код на php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если все столбцы в первой таблице — текстового типа, тогда для преобразования строки в дату можно воспользоваться, например, функцией [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), вторым параметром указав подходящий [шаблон](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) для парсинга (вроде бы `%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s` вполне подходит для вашего случая).

надеюсь, из примера будет понятно:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8ee1/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1 (s varchar (100), d varchar (100), t varchar (100));
create table t2 (s varchar (100), d varchar (100), data date, vremja time, data_i_vremja datetime);
insert into t1 values ("строка1", "ещё строка1", "27.06.2015 8:53:07"),
 ("строка2", "ещё строка2", "27.06.2015 11:48:57");
insert into t2 (s, d, data, vremja, data_i_vremja)
 select t1.s, t1.d,
 str_to_date (t1.t, "%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s"),
 str_to_date (t1.t, "%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s"),
 str_to_date (t1.t, "%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s")
 from t1;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8ee1/4/0)**:

```
|       s |           d |                   t |
|---------|-------------|---------------------|
| строка1 | ещё строка1 |  27.06.2015 8:53:07 |
| строка2 | ещё строка2 | 27.06.2015 11:48:57 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select t1.s, t1.d, str_to_date (t1.t, "%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s") as data from t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8ee1/4/1)**:

```
|       s |           d |                   data |
|---------|-------------|------------------------|
| строка1 | ещё строка1 | June, 27 2015 08:53:07 |
| строка2 | ещё строка2 | June, 27 2015 11:48:57 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from t2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8ee1/4/2)**:

```
|       s |           d |                   data |                    vremja |          data_i_vremja |
|---------|-------------|------------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
| строка1 | ещё строка1 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1970 08:53:07 | June, 27 2015 08:53:07 |
| строка2 | ещё строка2 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1970 11:48:57 | June, 27 2015 11:48:57 |
```

Comment: Спасибо) Поздно удалил комментарий. Заменил `%h` на `%H`

Comment: лучше на `%k` — `от 0 до 23`, а не `от 00 до 23`